# Newman CLI on Azure DevOps throwing connect etimedout

Tags: newman

I am trying to run postman collection on Azure DevOps. I added to command line tasks

1. npm install -g newman
2. newman run mycollections.json -e myenvironments.json --reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export Results\testreport.xml

When I run the collection I get the following message (Note for e.g. I have given a fake servername)

Post http://myservername [errored]
connect ETIMEDOUT ipaddress

I tried to set http_proxy but no luck. I want to find out is it because the agent doesn't have access to my on-premise server. But we have other release pipelines that run successfully.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by running self-hosted agent.

The error description wasn't great but when I ran newman from local machine with the same parameters it worked fine and that's when I realized using Microsoft-hosted agent runs on a VM in the cloud and won't have access on-premise resources.

We can find the IP of the agent and whitelist to provide access to on-premise resources but Microsoft-hosted agent IPs are not static and can change in the future.

I am not sure if this solution is optimal but it works great for my scenario.

I hope someone can find this answer helpful.